# Exponential of a symmetric tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix

Tags: matrices, reference-request, matrix-exponential, tridiagonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

Let $\alpha$ be a (strictly) positive real number. Consider the following tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix
$$
A=\alpha\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 &\cdots & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 &\ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \ddots & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 1 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

> **My question.** Does there exist a closed-form expression for $\exp(A)$?

I played around a little bit with the truncated series $\sum_{k=0}^N \frac{A^k}{k!}$ but I didn't manage to provide an answer to my question. Pointers to the literature are also welcome!

Comment: Does it matter that, with the $\alpha,$ it can be called a "Toeplitz matrix," or is an answer just based on the definition of $A$ OK for your purposes?

Comment: @coffeemath: $A$ is a particular Toeplitz matrix. Since the class of Toeplitz matrices has been extensively studied, I think it could be helpful to stress that $A$ falls into this class.

Comment: It is as important to consider it as a tridiagonal matrix. Here is a pointer to approximate solutions:(http://math.stackexchange.com/q/54915)

Comment: Silvia Noschese, Lionello Pasquini, and Lothar Reichel, [Tridiagonal Toeplitz Matrices: Properties and Novel Applications](http://www.math.kent.edu/~reichel/publications/toep3.pdf), 2006.

Comment: I assume you used [Sylvester's shift matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices#Construction:_The_clock_and_shift_matrices) $\Sigma_1=$  and its *N-1* powers in your expansion? Indices are distinct mod *N* , so $A=\alpha(\Sigma_1 + \Sigma_{N-1})$.  The expansion of the exponential telescopes to just *N/2* terms and the series are tractable.

Answer (score 7):

Hint (*too long for a comment*): tridiagonal Toeplitz matrices are known to have distinct eigenvalues, which can be explicitly calculated (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177957/eigenvalues-of-tridiagonal-symmetric-matrix-with-diagonal-entries-2-and-subdiago) and [here](https://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~lekheng/courses/302/notes14.pdf)). For the matrix in question, for example, the eigenvalues are $\lambda_k=2 \alpha \cos\left(\cfrac{k \pi}{n+1}\right)\,$, $k=1,2,\cdots,n$.

The matrix is therefore diagonalizable, and since the eigenvectors can also be explicitly calculated, it is possible to determine the invertible matrix $P$ and diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A=P\,D\,P^{-1}$.

Given that $\,A^n=P\,D^n\,P^{-1}\,$ it follows that $\,e^A=P\,e^D\,P^{-1}\,$ where $e^D$ is the diagonal matrix with $e^{\lambda_k}$ on the diagonal.

Comment: [+1} Good answer. I thought I had a shorter exact answer. This was not the case.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks. Your idea could still work out for small matrices, since there would be only a few $N^i \cdot {N^\intercal}^j$ to pre-calculate, but it becomes more tedious for large $n$.

Comment: @dxiv In fact, I had a bigger problem: $N$ and $N^T$ are not commuting matrices, $C:=NN^T-NN^T$ is almost a null matrix but for $C_{11}=1$ and $C_{nn}=-1...$

Comment: @JeanMarie You are right. Too bad, I'd have hoped there could be a simpler way.